# Map some names and values using java

Tags: java

I have a set of values as a repsonse like this.
from this

```
4,0,1581664239228,6,799,0,845,253,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1448,594,0,1276257,0,0,0,0,1100,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2047,2158,0,13,1
```

I have to map these values to below one..The order should be same like version: 4 , build: 0, tuneStartBaseUTCMS: 1581664239228 etc etc

```
version,build,tuneStartBaseUTCMS,ManifestDLStartTime,ManifestDLTotalTime,ManifestDLFailCount,VideoPlaylistDLStartTime,VideoPlaylistDLTotalTime,VideoPlaylistDLFailCount,AudioPlaylistDLStartTime,AudioPlaylistDLTotalTime,AudioPlaylistDLFailCount,VideoInitDLStartTime,VideoInitDLTotalTime,VideoInitDLFailCount,AudioInitDLStartTime,AudioInitDLTotalTime,AudioInitDLFailCount,VideoFragmentDLStartTime,VideoFragmentDLTotalTime,VideoFragmentDLFailCount,VideoBitRate,AudioFragmentDLStartTime,AudioFragmentDLTotalTime,AudioFragmentDLFailCount,AudioBitRate,drmLicenseAcqStartTime,drmLicenseAcqTotalTime,drmFailErrorCode,LicenseAcqPreProcessingDuration,LicenseAcqNetworkDuration,LicenseAcqPostProcDuration,VideoFragmentDecryptDuration,AudioFragmentDecryptDuration,gstPlayStartTime,gstFirstFrameTime,contentType,streamType,firstTune
```

I have written as follows...but it is not working as ex

```
String abcd = "4,0,1581664239228,6,799,0,845,253,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1448,594,0,1276257,0,0,0,0,1100,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2047,2158,0,13,1";
```

```
String valueName = "version,build,tuneStartBaseUTCMS,ManifestDLStartTime,ManifestDLTotalTime,ManifestDLFailCount,VideoPlaylistDLStartTime,VideoPlaylistDLTotalTime,VideoPlaylistDLFailCount,AudioPlaylistDLStartTime,AudioPlaylistDLTotalTime,AudioPlaylistDLFailCount,VideoInitDLStartTime,VideoInitDLTotalTime,VideoInitDLFailCount,AudioInitDLStartTime,AudioInitDLTotalTime,AudioInitDLFailCount,VideoFragmentDLStartTime,VideoFragmentDLTotalTime,VideoFragmentDLFailCount,VideoBitRate,AudioFragmentDLStartTime,AudioFragmentDLTotalTime,AudioFragmentDLFailCount,AudioBitRate,drmLicenseAcqStartTime,drmLicenseAcqTotalTime,drmFailErrorCode,LicenseAcqPreProcessingDuration,LicenseAcqNetworkDuration,LicenseAcqPostProcDuration,VideoFragmentDecryptDuration,AudioFragmentDecryptDuration,gstPlayStartTime,gstFirstFrameTime,contentType,streamType,firstTune";



String[] valueArr = abcd.split(",");

String[] valueNameArr = valueName.split(",");

List<String> valueList = Arrays.asList(valueArr);

List<String> valueNameList = Arrays.asList(valueNameArr);

System.out.println(valueList.size() + "jjj: " + "valueNameList::: " + valueNameList.size());
LinkedHashMap<String, String> result = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

for (String name : valueNameList) {
    System.out.println("name: " + name);
    for (String value : valueList) {
      System.out.println("value: " + value);
      result.put(name, value);
    }
}

System.out.println("RESULT::::::::::::::::::::::::::::" + result);
```

Result prints:

```
{version=1, build=1, tuneStartBaseUTCMS=1, ManifestDLStartTime=1, ManifestDLTotalTime=1, ManifestDLFailCount=1, VideoPlaylistDLStartTime=1, VideoPlaylistDLTotalTime=1, VideoPlaylistDLFailCount=1, AudioPlaylistDLStartTime=1, AudioPlaylistDLTotalTime=1, AudioPlaylistDLFailCount=1, VideoInitDLStartTime=1, VideoInitDLTotalTime=1, VideoInitDLFailCount=1, AudioInitDLStartTime=1, AudioInitDLTotalTime=1, AudioInitDLFailCount=1, VideoFragmentDLStartTime=1, VideoFragmentDLTotalTime=1, VideoFragmentDLFailCount=1, VideoBitRate=1, AudioFragmentDLStartTime=1, AudioFragmentDLTotalTime=1, AudioFragmentDLFailCount=1, AudioBitRate=1, drmLicenseAcqStartTime=1, drmLicenseAcqTotalTime=1, drmFailErrorCode=1, LicenseAcqPreProcessingDuration=1, LicenseAcqNetworkDuration=1, LicenseAcqPostProcDuration=1, VideoFragmentDecryptDuration=1, AudioFragmentDecryptDuration=1, gstPlayStartTime=1, gstFirstFrameTime=1, contentType=1, streamType=1, firstTune=1}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there not supposed to be a one-to-one relationship between `abcd` values and `valueName` ? If there is one-to-one, then an inner loop is wrong isn't it.

```
   String abcd = "4,0,1581664239228,6,799,0,845,253,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1448,594,0,1276257,0,0,0,0,1100,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2047,2158,0,13,1";
   String valueName = "version,build,tuneStartBaseUTCMS,ManifestDLStartTime,ManifestDLTotalTime,ManifestDLFailCount,VideoPlaylistDLStartTime,VideoPlaylistDLTotalTime,VideoPlaylistDLFailCount,AudioPlaylistDLStartTime,AudioPlaylistDLTotalTime,AudioPlaylistDLFailCount,VideoInitDLStartTime,VideoInitDLTotalTime,VideoInitDLFailCount,AudioInitDLStartTime,AudioInitDLTotalTime,AudioInitDLFailCount,VideoFragmentDLStartTime,VideoFragmentDLTotalTime,VideoFragmentDLFailCount,VideoBitRate,AudioFragmentDLStartTime,AudioFragmentDLTotalTime,AudioFragmentDLFailCount,AudioBitRate,drmLicenseAcqStartTime,drmLicenseAcqTotalTime,drmFailErrorCode,LicenseAcqPreProcessingDuration,LicenseAcqNetworkDuration,LicenseAcqPostProcDuration,VideoFragmentDecryptDuration,AudioFragmentDecryptDuration,gstPlayStartTime,gstFirstFrameTime,contentType,streamType,firstTune";

   String[] list1 = abcd.split(",");
   String[] list2 = valueName.split(",");

   if (list1.length == list2.length) {

       for (int x = 0; x < list1.length; x++) {
           System.out.println(list2[x] + ":" + list1[x]);
       }
   }
```

Simply split and iterate

**result**

```
version:4
build:0
tuneStartBaseUTCMS:1581664239228
ManifestDLStartTime:6
ManifestDLTotalTime:799
ManifestDLFailCount:0
VideoPlaylistDLStartTime:845
VideoPlaylistDLTotalTime:253
VideoPlaylistDLFailCount:0
AudioPlaylistDLStartTime:0
AudioPlaylistDLTotalTime:0
AudioPlaylistDLFailCount:0
VideoInitDLStartTime:0
VideoInitDLTotalTime:0
VideoInitDLFailCount:0
AudioInitDLStartTime:0
AudioInitDLTotalTime:0
AudioInitDLFailCount:0
VideoFragmentDLStartTime:1448
VideoFragmentDLTotalTime:594
VideoFragmentDLFailCount:0
VideoBitRate:1276257
AudioFragmentDLStartTime:0
AudioFragmentDLTotalTime:0
AudioFragmentDLFailCount:0
AudioBitRate:0
drmLicenseAcqStartTime:1100
drmLicenseAcqTotalTime:0
drmFailErrorCode:0
LicenseAcqPreProcessingDuration:0
LicenseAcqNetworkDuration:0
LicenseAcqPostProcDuration:0
VideoFragmentDecryptDuration:0
AudioFragmentDecryptDuration:0
gstPlayStartTime:2047
gstFirstFrameTime:2158
contentType:0
streamType:13
firstTune:1
```

Answer (score 5):

Your loop is wrong
Try this

```
for(int i = 0; i < valueList.size(); i++){
  result.put(valueNameList(i), valueList(i));  
}
```

Comment: Why are `Lists` even necessary?

Comment: I build on existing implementation of code. Maybe later they are necessary. But now Immutable Lists are not necessary.